# pull non-wp site into content area of wordpress -or- pull wp header into non wp site?

Tags: menus, customization, page-template, headers, static-website

I am building a site which has a ecommerce nature that is not able to be tied directly into wordpress. What my goal is to have a constant header that is generated by my wordpress header on all pages including the ecommerce store.

Now my question is what route is best:

a) Pull wordpress header into e-commerce site 
b) Pull e-commerce site into the "content" area of my wordpress site via a custom template, this is my perfered option as I could keep the footer and rest of the theme going on.

So how would I accomplish this? I imagine making a custom page template pulling in the index.php of the e-commerce store is the way to go, does anyone have an example or tips on this as I have not made a custom template strucutre in WP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tight integration (loading either inside of other one) without much functionality overlap might come with considerable performance penalty. It might or might not be relevant for you.

Since the issue can be abstracted to "how to transfer fragment of page to external site" I would probably generate that fragment in WP and make other side retrieve in some way. For example via Ajax request or just reading file with cached fragment.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, do you have any further reading I can do on this subject, a still a little foggy by your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @matt I am hesitant to offer anything very specific since it can be opposite of what you actual situation requires :) You could start by reading up on [Ajax](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for convenient way to send data (although in your situation I would probably be requesting via PHP and not JS) and work your desired markup to pass into that.

Comment: thanks, the thing is its just a very basic webstore I hope to pull into WP as we will be using wordpress for the navigation sidebar etc...thats why I was thinking of just making a custom template, the webstore has been built responsive so it should work well, at least I thought.